# What is the most efficient protobuf type (in C++) for storing ipv4 or ipv6 address? My address is a boost::asio::ip::address_v4 (or v6)

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers, boost-asio

I read that protobuf has a type called "**bytes**" which can store arbitrary number of bytes and is the equivalent of "C++ string". The reason why I don't prefer to use "bytes" is that it expects input as a C++ string i.e., boost IP will need to be converted to a string. Now my concern lies here : I want to perform serialize and send the encoded protobuf message over TCP socket. I want to ensure that the **encoded message size is as small as possible**.

Currently, I am using the below .proto file :

```
syntax = "proto2";

message profile

{

repeated **uint32** localEndpoint = 1;

repeated **uint32** remoteEndpoint = 2;

}
```

In order to save boost IP in the protobuf message, I am first converting boost IP into byte-format array by using "boost::asio::ip::address_v4::to_bytes()". So for a v4 IP, resultant array size is 4. Then I am converting 1st 4 bytes from the resultant byte-array into one uint32_t number and then storing in "localEndpoint" field of the protobuf message. Likewise, I repeat for the next 4 bytes (for v6). I am taking 4 bytes at a time so as to utilize full 32 bits of the uint32.

Hence for a v4 address, 1 occurrence of "localEndpoint" field is used.
Similarly, for a v6 address, 4 occurrence of "localEndpoint" field is used.

Please allow me to highlight that if I had used "bytes" here, my input string itself would have been of size 15 bytes for a v4 ip like 111.111.111.111

Using uint32 instead of "bytes" does save me some encoded-data-size but I am looking for a more efficient protobuf type requiring lesser number of bytes.

Sorry for a long description but I wanted to explain my query in details. Please help me.. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Efficient in what sense? Size? It depends (if everything is in the same subnet e.g.). Pack/unpack performance? Those are diffrent goals.

Comment: Yeah Size. I want to keep the size of the protobuf encoded data as small as possible.

Comment: That would still depend on the data. Protobuf has varint encoding (which is 1-5 bytes for 32bit integers). But using some domain knowledge you might get a lot shorter (e.g. masking out the netmask)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An ipv4 address should require exactly 4 bytes. If you're somehow getting 8, you're doing something wrong - are you perhaps hex-encoding it? You don't need that here. Likewise, ipv6 should be 16 bytes.

4 bytes with a usually-set high byte is most effectively stored as `fixed32` - varint would be overhead here, due to the high bits. 16 bytes is more subtle - I'd go with `bytes` (field header plus length), since it is simpler to form into a union, and if the field-number is large, it avoids having to pay for multiple multi-byte field headers (a length prefix of 16 will always be single-byte).

I'd then create a union of these via `oneof`:

```
oneof ip_addr {
    fixed32 v4 = 1;
    bytes v6 = 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for your reply!
By mistake I wrote 8-bytes for ipv4. I have corrected it as 4-bytes in my question. Thanks for that :)

One thing I want to ask you is that can I use "oneof" if my field "localEndpoint"  is repeated? I mean to say that my one "profile" message can have any among :
-> 2 ipv4 addresses
-> OR  2 ipv6 addresses
-> OR 1 ipv4 + 1 ipv6 addresses.
in the field "localEndpoint".

So in that case, is "oneof" usage correct? I think that a "oneof" cannot be repeated. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hello Marc,

I wanted to let you know that I tried using fixed32 and fixed64 protobuf types and it has helped me save quite some bytes on the encoded data size. Protobuf message I created which is capable for storing one or multiple v4/v6 IPs :

`message IpAddress
{
    message IpAddressTypes
    {
        message V6Type
        {
            repeated fixed64 v6IpAddress = 1 [packed=true];
        }
        oneof IpTypes
        {
            fixed32 v4Ip = 1;
            V6Type v6Ip = 2;
        }
    }
    repeated IpAddressTypes ipAddress = 1;
}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of fixed32/fixed64 types and also highlighting about "oneof".
Please correct me if you find anything wrong with my protobuf message.

Comment: @SanjanaGupta I literally don't understand that proto at all; a v6 address is 16 bytes, so I don't understand what `fixed64` is doing. If you're storing exactly 2 longs as a repeated, I'm wondering why you didn't just use `bytes`, or just exactly 2 longs as dfferent fields; and storing the address type explicitly seems unnecessary and redundant (the "oneof" already tells you which "one of"). So ... yeah, I don't understand it.